# How to send a serialized class over sockets using TCP protocal in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

To clarify, this class holds important client information that has to arrive in its entirety without missing or corrupted information.
I need to send this class as a variable that holds some client information from a client to a server, and the server stores that variable in an array.

I could send it using ObjectOutputStream but is it safe to use this to send client information? If the client information arrives makes or breaks my project. (I can only use java in my project)

I tried searching across the internet for a relateable solution but none was sufficient enough.

My knowledge specifically in how to explain the Java language in English is limited since I didn't learn this language using English, so I hope you understand my question.

EDIT: Added the class.

```
public class ClientInformation implements Serializable 
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8904366211043587433L;
    private int arrplace;
    private int mode;
    private int ip;
    private String myusername;
    private String username;
    private int password;
    private Dimension screenResolution;
    public ClientInformation (int ip, String myusername, String username, int password,Dimension screenResolution, int mode, int arrplace) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.myusername = myusername;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.screenResolution = screenResolution;
        this.mode = mode;
    }
    public int getarrplace()
    {
        return arrplace;
    }
    public int getmode()
    {
        return mode;
    }
    public int getip()
    {
        return ip;
    }
    public String getmyusername()
    {
        return myusername;
    }
    public String getusername()
    {
        return username;
    }
    public int getpass()
    {
        return password;
    }
    public Dimension getscreenRes()
    {
        return screenResolution;
    }
    public void setarrplace(int arrplace)
    {
        this.arrplace = arrplace;
    }
    public void setmode (int mode)
    {
        this.mode = mode;
    }
    public void setmyusername (String myusername)
    {
        this.myusername = myusername;
    }
    public void setusername (String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public void setpass(int password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public void setscreenRes(Dimension screenResolution)
    {
        this.screenResolution = screenResolution;
    }
}
```

Comment: Parsing the data is completly up to you ( If the server does not have any restrictions)

Comment: Could you send us an outline of your class

Comment: You could use ObjectOutputStream or convert the fields into bytes yourself and think of a structure to determine on the other end what is what. Or you could use JsonReader and JsonWriter to serialize and deserialize your object and then send it to the server to be stored

Comment: I would prefer the Json way, but if you want to store the entire instance in as little space as possible, I would recommend to convert the fields inside the class into bytes manually and think about a structure to arange them, so that they could be read back in later

Comment: Please provide the class you want to send to the server

Comment: And by the way tcp will always send data in it's entirety. If the connection closes before it is completed, then there will be an error thrown somewhere.

Comment: I added the class that I would like to send, my problem is mainly that the class may arrive over the internet with missing information. Which can result in further errors in some other code my program. I didn't study JSON  for my project so I can't really do it now, (nearing end phases)..

Comment: I added a full implementation of reading and writing your class from and to and input- or outputstream. Please don't forget to add your getters and setter methods back in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. I made an entire implementation for you, which writes its data directly on the stream. I would recommand using eigher an SSL Socket or an encrypted stream (CipherInput- and CipherOutputStream).
To write this class to a stream just call writeTo on it and pass in an Outputstream or to read in pass an InputStream to its constructor.

> Note: DON'T forget to close (and flush) the streams after calling the corresponding methods. I didn't make them close inside the writeTo method and the constructor, because you might still need the streams to read or write more data.

Here you go (I tested it. It is fully functional and will even write and read null values correctly):

```
public static final class ClientInformation implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8904366211043587433L;
    
    private static final Charset CHARSET = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

    private int arrplace;
    private int mode;
    private int ip;
    private String myusername;
    private String username;
    private final int password;
    private Dimension screenResolution;

    public ClientInformation(int ip,
                             String myusername,
                             String username,
                             int password,
                             Dimension screenResolution,
                             int mode,
                             int arrplace) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.myusername = myusername;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.screenResolution = screenResolution;
        this.mode = mode;
        this.arrplace = arrplace;
    }

    public ClientInformation(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        int l;
        byte[] sb = null, ib = new byte[4];

        // Read arrplace
        readFully(in, ib, 0, 4);
        arrplace = getInt(ib, 0);

        // Read mode
        readFully(in, ib, 0, 4);
        mode = getInt(ib, 0);

        // Read ip
        readFully(in, ib, 0, 4);
        ip = getInt(ib, 0);

        // Read myusername
        readFully(in, ib, 0, 4);
        l = getInt(ib, 0);
        sb = resize(sb, l);
        if (l >= 0) {
            readFully(in, sb, 0, l);
            myusername = new String(sb, 0, l, CHARSET);
        } else {
            myusername = null;
        }

        // Read username
        readFully(in, ib, 0, 4);
        l = getInt(ib, 0);
        sb = resize(sb, l);
        if (l >= 0) {
            readFully(in, sb, 0, l);
            username = new String(sb, 0, l, CHARSET);
        } else {
            username = null;
        }

        // Read password
        readFully(in, ib, 0, 4);
        password = getInt(ib, 0);

        // Read screenWidth
        readFully(in, ib, 0, 4);
        int screenWidth = getInt(ib, 0);

        // Read screenHeight
        readFully(in, ib, 0, 4);
        int screenHeight = getInt(ib, 0);

        screenResolution = new Dimension(
                screenWidth,
                screenHeight
        );
    }

    public void writeTo(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        String s;
        int l;
        byte[] sb, ib = new byte[4];

        // Write arrplace
        putInt(ib, 0, arrplace);
        os.write(ib, 0, 4);

        // Write mode
        putInt(ib, 0, mode);
        os.write(ib, 0, 4);

        // Write ip
        putInt(ib, 0, ip);
        os.write(ib, 0, 4);

        // Write myusername
        s = myusername;
        if (s != null) {
            sb = s.getBytes(CHARSET);
            putInt(ib, 0, l = sb.length);
            os.write(ib, 0, 4);
            os.write(sb, 0, l);
        } else {
            putInt(ib, 0, -1);
            os.write(ib, 0, 4);
        }

        // Write username
        s = username;
        if (s != null) {
            sb = s.getBytes(CHARSET);
            putInt(ib, 0, l = sb.length);
            os.write(ib, 0, 4);
            os.write(sb, 0, l);
        } else {
            putInt(ib, 0, -1);
            os.write(ib, 0, 4);
        }

        // Write password
        putInt(ib, 0, password);
        os.write(ib, 0, 4);

        Dimension screenRes = screenResolution;

        // Write screenRes.getWidth()
        putInt(ib, 0, (int) screenRes.getWidth()); // Get width actually returns an integer
        os.write(ib, 0, 4);

        // Write screenRes.getHeight()
        putInt(ib, 0, (int) screenRes.getHeight()); // Get height actually returns an integer
        os.write(ib, 0, 4);
    }

    static byte[] resize(byte[] b, int newLen) {
        if (newLen < 0) return b;
        if (b == null || b.length < newLen) {
            return new byte[newLen];
        } else return b;
    }

    static void putInt(byte[] b, int off, int val) {
        b[off + 3] = (byte) (val);
        b[off + 2] = (byte) (val >>> 8);
        b[off + 1] = (byte) (val >>> 16);
        b[off] = (byte) (val >>> 24);
    }

    static int getInt(byte[] b, int off) {
        return ((b[off + 3] & 0xFF)) +
                ((b[off + 2] & 0xFF) << 8) +
                ((b[off + 1] & 0xFF) << 16) +
                ((b[off]) << 24);
    }

    static void readFully(InputStream in, byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int n = 0;
        while (n < len) {
            int count = in.read(b, off + n, len - n);
            if (count < 0) {
                throw new EOFException();
            }
            n += count;
        }
    }

    // Don't forget to add all the getters and setter you had
}
```

---

Here is the sample code I used to test this class:

```
try {
    // Serialize
    ClientInformation info = new ClientInformation(
            30,
            "MyUsername",
            "My Real Username",
            3485,
            new Dimension(300, 200),
            19,
            20
    );

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    info.writeTo(bos);
    bos.flush();

    // Deserialize
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
    ClientInformation receivedInfo = new ClientInformation(in);

    System.out.println(receivedInfo.ip);
    System.out.println(receivedInfo.myusername);
    System.out.println(receivedInfo.username);
    System.out.println(receivedInfo.password);
    System.out.println(receivedInfo.screenResolution);
    System.out.println(receivedInfo.mode);
    System.out.println(receivedInfo.arrplace);
} catch (Throwable tr) {
    tr.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I hope you still see this @Sea

Comment: Well done IntoVoid.  @Sea that is good code you can use. However, pls look at the Java guidelines anyway, plus the code to creating the SSLSocket is in the second link I sent you.

Comment: yeah they should definitely use a secure connection

Comment: @Sea it is fair you upvote and mark as the answer to your question the IntoVoid's one, but I am happy if you upvote mine as well, as I gave you some useful tip.

Comment: Thank you @MarcoTizzano . Really kind of you.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is strongly discouraged to use serialization/deserialization of sensitive data classes, you can still implement it, but it is at least recommended to strictly follow the *Oracle Java security guidelines* in relation to that topic:
[8 Serialization and Deserialization](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/MSC00-J.+Use+SSLSocket+rather+than+Socket+for+secure+data+exchange)
However, I also recommend you to use *SSL Socket*, instead of simple Java Socket, which guarantees the security of the communication channel, thus of your sensitive data that you're going to serialize over the `ObjectOutputstream`, and will prevent any tampering attempts from malicious users.
You can find some useful examples of SSLSocket usage at Java Cert Code standard page, at this [link](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/MSC00-J.+Use+SSLSocket+rather+than+Socket+for+secure+data+exchange). Look at the "Compliant Solution" and try the example there.

Comment: Regarding the safety of information, it's not really that necessary for me at the moment. I only need to move that class containing information across clients in a way that doesn't miss out on lost information.

Comment: You might want to reconsider that. I do know something about it as I work on financial software. As long as you are dealing with "sensitive data" (i.e. username and passwords), your first focus must be on securing them, in particular when you have to send them over a Java stream, not just fearing with the possibility of loosing the data. Serializing the object with ObjectOutputStream is still a considerable solution. You actually asked whereas it was "safe" in this way, and I gave you an answer: yes but it is strongly recommended that you follow the security guidelines I showed you above.